# WPF binding model properties to data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question, it might be simple but I cannot find a solution. I am having a simple model that looks like this:

```
public class FlagAnalysis
{
    public DateTime DailyTimestampInterval { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public int[] Flags { get; set; } = {};
}
```

In the view model I have a ObservableCollection of these models

```
 public ObservableCollection<FlagAnalysis> FlagValues { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FlagAnalysis>();
```

Now what I am trying to do is to create a data grid where values of DailyTimestampInterval will be the column header titles and Flags would be column cells. It should look like this:

```
  02.03.2018 | 03.03.2018 | 04.03.2018
  --------------------------------------
       1     |      0     |     3
       2     |      2     |     1
```

I have tried something like

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FlagValues}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding DailyTimestampInterval}" Binding="{Binding CFlags, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

but with no luck. Is there a solution for this problem?

EDIT:

I check output console it writes something like

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DailyTimestampInterval; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=35744420); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')

Comment: is my understanding correct, that you want to have a dynamic amount of columns depending on how many FlagValues you have ? If so, you sample can't work because you are defining just one column....